# Proving two sets of even integers are equal

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

This is a question I found in the proof book I am practicing in. This seems like a ridiculous thing to prove, so I don't know what the author is looking for.

Prove

$\{n \in \mathbb{Z}:n$ is even$\}$ = $\{n \in \mathbb{Z}:n-1$  is odd $\}$

Normally I would prove that the first set is a subset of the second set and the converse of that. Here all I can think to do is show:

if $n-1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is odd $n-1=2k-1$

so $n=2k$ implies n is even so the two sets are equal.Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: No, because you started "if $n- 1\in Z" so you have really just proved that the second set is a subset of the first.  Now, as you yourself suggested, you also have to prove it the other way.  "If n is in the first set,, then n= 2k.  n- 1= 2k- 1, and odd number so the first set is a subset of the second.  That is, you have proved "subset" in both directions so the sets are equal.

Comment: The definition of odd number is not "an integer $n$ such that there is some integer $k$ such that $n=2k-1$". It's "an integer which is not even", i.e. "an integer $n$ such that $n\ne 2k$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$". Basically, what the author asks you to do is to prove that if $2$ does not divide $n$, then $2$ must divide $n+1$.

Comment: The point of this exercise may be to really think about your definitions of odd and even integers.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well, maybe not.  I wasn't sure what the OP was trying to suggest, though I may well have just muddied the waters.  In any case, I'll delete my (probably unhelpful) comment.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  Right.  Why I deleted the comment.

Comment: @Gae.S. would it be better to say that an odd integer is a number $n$ such that $n=2c+1$ for $c \in \mathbb{z}$ therefore if $n-1=2c+1$ since $n-1$ is odd, then $n=2c$ so $n$ is even?

Comment: How about n is even if and only if n-1 is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Showing that the defining formulas for the two sets are satisfied for exactly the same elements is one way of showing that two sets are equal. It's basically equivalent to showing that each set is a subset of the other.

The point here is that formally you have to do the argument both ways: Any $n$ such that $n-1$ is odd is even. That is what you have shown. However, for any even $n$, we have $n-1$ odd. This you technically haven't shown, and as such you aren't done. However, it ought to be enough to simply point out that the same argument works backwards as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial instinct to prove that each set is a subset of the other would work here, and shouldn't be difficult. All you'd need is to state formally that n being even (and thus in the first set) necessitates n-1 being odd (thus n is in the second set), and vice versa.

This would show that any element of either set is also in the other, and hence they are subsets of one another.